# How to detect which files are created when running a command

Tags: make, c++, tree

I'm trying to understand what files or build artifacts are created by the build system of a C++ project.

There are 3 steps to building this project:

- `./autogen.sh`
- `./configure`
- `make`

Is there a way I could compare outputs of the `tree` command between running each command? Or something along these lines ...

Comment: If you store project in Git repository you could use `git ls-files -o` instead of `tree`. That would only find new files.

Comment: @Quasímodo No. Command line. Perhaps I should learn a GUI!

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Thanks! That's pretty close to what I want. I can diff that.

Answer (score 2):

- [chkinstall](https://asic-linux.com.mx/%7Eizto/checkinstall/)
- `strace -e file -fF command`
- `sudo inotifywait -e modify -e attrib -e move -e delete -e close_write -m -r /`

The second command could produce a ton of output if you have any other applications running. You could switch to single user mode to get rid of the noise.